# Typescript dependencies on WebPack

Tags: typescript, webpack

Basically I have a file: 
**index.ts** which imports dependencies from other .ts files.

What should I configure on webpack.config.js and tsconfig so I could be able to export that to "/dist" with not only index.ts compiled to index.js, but also all dependencies are included and compiled individually as well to .js

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please provide the code showing what you have already tried. This will show people at what level to pitch their answers.

Comment: First, to confirm, do you want to compile all ts files to a single js file?  If so, you'll need to use Webpack with a TypeScript loader such as [ts-loader](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader); you can follow one of the examples there.  If you want each ts file compiled to a separate js file, then just use `tsc`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use https://cli.angular.io/
or any seed project from github